# Does Apache Ignite thin JDBC driver work with a cache having Atomicity = TRANSACTIONAL

Tags: java, jdbc, ignite

I have been reading the documentation for hours but I could not find a clear answer.
Apache Ignite and Grid Gain documentation states that for a Cache I can use ATOMIC or  TRANSACTIONAL or TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT [here](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/CacheAtomicityMode.html)
For TRANSACTIONAL it states that

> "In this mode, transactional consistency is guaranteed for key-value
> API operations only"

There is no mentioning of JDBC anywhere.

So, I connect to GridGain cluster via JDBC and I **only** use INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements via JDBC connection on caches that are created by SQL statements like this. My cache is **TRANSACTIONAL**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FOO(
ID NUMBER(10,0),
NAME VARCHAR2(100),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) WITH "TEMPLATE=PARTITIONED,ATOMICITY=TRANSACTIONAL";
```

My JDBC usage is like this. Here I disable auto commit and run a few statements and then commit manually.

```
connect.setAutoCommit(false);

PreparedStatement st1.executeUpdate();  
PreparedStatement st2.executeQuery();
...//other prepared statements executed
connect.commit();
```

I have performed some tests with two data nodes in a cluster and I don't see a problem. So by definition a JDBC connection must be using pessimistic locks just like Key-Value API.
**Is my assumption correct ? And is my JDBC usage safe or not ?**

Answer (score 0):

Ignite doesn't currently support SQL transactions.

You can *use* the table using SQL/JDBC but if, for example, you do a big update or need to change two records atomically, it's possible that some, but not all, of the updates to be recorded.

If you need transactions, you would need to use the key-value API rather than SQL/JDBC.

Comment: I am writing this comment to help others in the future. According to my tests Ignite supports transactions only if cache has "transactional_snapshot" attribute. This attribute is flagged as "experimental" in documentation. And also this attribute makes the cache MVCC. So if you are using JDBC and accept to work with an experimental feature that uses MVCC, Ignite supports transactions/rollbacks etc. Because I have seen it rolling back a transaction with multiple statements in a cluster successfully. Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: Yeah, but don't use it, really. It's going away: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=191334475 It will probably come back in Ignite 3.